# Soliton solution for a diffusive system

Tags: diffusion, solitons

With a simple model for bacterial diffusion, I get this partial derivative equation :
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial x^2} + d_1 n -d_2 n^2$$

where $n(x,t)$ is the population of bacteria, $d_1$ the rate of proliferation and $d_2 n $ is the rate of death for a bacteria.

I know that there should exist some soliton solution going from the solution $n=0$ to the solution $n=\frac{d_1}{d_2}$ but I have no clue how to treat such a problem. What are some methods to get about those soliton solutions?

Answer (score 1):

At least for an equilibrium situation, where $\dfrac{\partial n}{\partial t}=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial n}{\partial x}=0$, you would easily see that

$$d_1 n - d_2 n^2=0,$$

with the  two solutions you anticipated.

I am not sure what you mean with a soliton solution for an equation like these, as the basis of your equation is not a wave equation. Probably you mean solutions that also satisfy the equation:

$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 n}{\partial x^2}$$

But it would lead to the same result. I hope this is at least a partially satisfying answer.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a solution (soliton= like $n(x,t) = f(x-ct)$ avec $f(u \rightarrow -\infty) =d_1/d_2$ and $f(u \rightarrow +\infty) =0$ even if it's a diffusion equation. Physically, the information I think is intersting is to find out how evolve a border between the two solution, what it's lengthscale and so on

Comment: @sailx Ok, I understand your question better now. You may want to look into the error function, as it might help you. I am however a bit afraid for the quadratic term in the equation.

Comment: Also, this may be more appropriate on the math stackexchange.